# Need a small regex help

Tags: validation, regular-expressions

Needed some help while constructing the below pattern for salesforce contact Phone Field

```
Condition1: must start with ‘0’
Condition2: can only be followed by digits and spaces.
Condition3: minimum number of digit is 11.
```

I tried with `NOT(REGEX(Phone,"[0]{1}[0-9 ]+$")) in validation rule,` but this is not working also i noticed , Phone being the standard field after I enter number as 0123456789 automatically it becomes (012) 345-6789

Does I need to consider this change as well in the validation that I am creating. and is my REGEX is correct?

Comment: Why are you trying to write a validation rule on phone number?

Comment: Why? we wanted to get good quality data and that's the business need. We get the data from pardot marketing system and we wanted to maintain similar data validation for phone number in Salesforce so that while sales users creates the contact it should have proper validation.